# Bash method return value is always modulo 256

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script method that returns the input value as such. The return value however, is always the value modulo 256. I googled for a while and found [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) article that said it's always modulo 256 (something I'd already guessed), but didn't explain why. Can someone shed some light on why it does this?

```
var=$1
hello () {
    return $var
}
hello

ret=$?
echo $ret

>>> ./script 300
>>> 44
```

Comment: [Because of POSIX compliance](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html).

Comment: Or perhaps more directly, section 2.8.2 of the POSIX [Shell Command Langauge](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) specification, which references the `WEXITSTATUS()` macro documented for use with the [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) function.  The latter explicitly says that the exit status it provides is the bottom 8 bits of the value passed to `exit()` or `_Exit()`.

Comment: The `return` statement is not intended to return arbitrary data as the return value of a function. It is *only* intended to set a one-byte exit status. Shell functions aren't really functions in the usual sense

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf and other, thanks for the explanation and links. Could someone post an answer so that I could accept it as the right answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The return value is limited to 1 byte (8 bits). Taking the least significant byte from an integer is equivalent to modulo 256 (2^8).

Comment: My question was *why* that is. Why is there a 1 byte limit on the return value?

Comment: The reason is that lower bits are reserved for operating system failures.  Try to kill the program and see the return value then. Normally, specs have some obscure way of saying thing but if you come to the man page of `bash(1)`, you'll find it there.